# Hibernate4 custom cache provider

Tags: hibernate, caching, dynacache

I was trying to create dynacache as hibernate4's second level cache. There is custom implementation for this using hibernate 3(http://wpcertification.blogspot.se/2012/01/using-dynacache-as-cache-implementation.html). In this blog the code uses cacheprovider class, with some amount of googling I found hibernate regionfactory is what is used in hibernate4 and cacheprovider is no longer supported. Not sure if my understanding is right here. Have been looking all around but couldn't find much input on this. Also any suggestion or link that can suggest how to implement Dynacache as second level caching for hibernate4.

Thanks in advance